# Validate fields before updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, validation

I am stuck on attempting to validate my form data before I am able to perform and AJAX update. So basically what I am trying to achieve is validate the form input data before the ajax update function. I do not know where I would place the functions for validation inside the method below:
My AJAX updating function:

```
$("#updateUser").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser",
                data: $("#updateForm").serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#alert").show();
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                } 
            });
        });
```

This is the form I am attempting to validate:

```
    <form id="updateForm">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" /> 
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                    <br /> 
                    User name:
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                    <br /> 
                    Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                    <br /> 
                    Authority
                    <input type="text" name="authority" id="authority" />
                    <br />
                </form>
```

Any suggestions please help, I am new to javascript. Thanks

Comment: $("#updateUser").click(function() { if (!valid($("#updateForm")) return false; ... - where and what is #updateUser

Comment: #updateUser is actually a button after this form. I forgot to post that within the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your validation code before sending ajax call.

```
$("#updateUser").click(function() {
var allright = true;
if ($('#name').val() == ''){
    allright = false;
    highlight_input('#name');
}
if (allright){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser",
            data: $("#updateForm").serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $("#alert").show();
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            } 
        });
}
    });
```

Comment: sure :) you're free to do how you feel this. If there are a lot of logic then better way is to separate these into some functions and use them with logic conditions

Comment: Ok awesome, could how would I split like a length check into a function then call it before the ajax post?

Comment: look at http://api.jquery.com/ - there you can find out information about useful jquery functions. you need something like http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)** you can do in below way

```
$("#updateUser").click(function() {

   var form = $( "#updateForm" );
   form.validate();
    if(form.valid()){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser",
            data: $("#updateForm").serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $("#alert").show();
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            } 
        });
      }
    });
```